# How to empty the contents of a div and insert a working iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a function that empties a video container of its contents (thumbnail / playbutton) and replace it with an iframe of for example vimeo or youtube.

So far I got this:

```
replaceIframe(){
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const videoContainer = document.querySelector('#landingspage .video-container');
    const iframe = document.querySelector('#landingspage .iframe-container').innerHTML;
    const iframeHTML = parser.parseFromString(iframe, "text/html");

    console.log(iframeHTML);

    if(videoContainer !== null){
        videoContainer.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            videoContainer.replaceChildren(iframeHTML);
        });
    }
}
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChildren' on 'Element': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'DIV'.
    at HTMLDivElement.
```

How can I fix this? I first tried it without the parser object but then it just replaces the contents with a string of the iframe html.

Comment: the problem here is that `parser.parseFromString` returns an `HTMLDocument`, which is basically an entire web page, containing the `html` tag, `head` tag, `body` tag, and so on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString

Comment: the error explains it: you're trying to append a `document` object (the entire web page) to a div element, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `videoContainer.innerHTML = iframeHTML` instead of `videoContainer.replaceChildren(iframeHTML)`;

Comment: This replaces the contents with: `[object HTMLDocument]`

Comment: Then convert to string `iframeHTML`